# nodeJS with ts : module declares component locally, but it is not exported

Tags: node.js, typescript, model, export, seed

In my nodeJS app I have a models and seeders folder, I created an address.model.ts schema like that :

---

```
export {};
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const addressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  street: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  number: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  codePostal: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'codePostal'  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  longitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  },
  latitude: {
    type: Number,
    required: false,
  }
});

const ALLOWED_FIELDS = ['id', 'street', 'number','city', 'codePostal', 'country'];


/**
 * @typedef Address
 */
const Address = mongoose.model('Address', addressSchema);
Address.ALLOWED_FIELDS = ALLOWED_FIELDS;
module.exports = Address;
```

and addresses.ts for seed like that :

```
import faker from 'faker'
import {
  Address
} from '../src/api/models/address.model'

export const seedAdresses = async () => {
  try {
    const quantity = 10
    const adresses = []

    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
      adresses.push(
        new Address({
          street   : faker.address.streetName(),
          number   : faker.address.streetAddress(),
          city     : faker.address.city(),
          country  : faker.address.country(),
          longitude: faker.address.longitude(),
          latitude : faker.address.latitude(),

        })
      )
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

seedAdresses()
```

I got an error when import Address :

> module '"../src/api/models/address.model"' declare 'Address' locally, but it is not exported.
>   I don't understand why it's not exported although  module.exports = Address; exist in my schema!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you are using CommonJS exports with ES6 imports/exports, use `export { Address };` rather than `export {};` in address.model.ts.

You should also consider using `import { Schema, model } from "mongoose"` to stay consistent with ES6.